# How would I make players on teams detect parts of a player?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am using **WorldToScreenPoint** and **GetPartsObscuringTarget.** What I am trying to fix is that a player must detect parts of player on a different team. For example, there is a player on a team alone trying to find other players by detecting one of their humanoid parts. The script only detect parts inside the **Workspace.**

I've tried using **Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()** and a nested loop to go through players if they are on the same team or not. This didn't worked. I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 weeks.

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = workspace:FindFirstChild(Player.Name)

game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    for _, object in pairs(Character:GetDescendants()) do
        if object:IsA("Part") or object:IsA("MeshPart") then
            if not object:IsDescendantOf(game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character) then
                local object2,visible = workspace.CurrentCamera:WorldToScreenPoint(object.Position)
                if visible == true then
                    local pos1 = workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame.Position
                    local pos2 = object.Position
                    local castPoints = {pos1,pos2}
                    local ignoreList = {game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character, object}
                    local obstructs = workspace.CurrentCamera:GetPartsObscuringTarget(castPoints,ignoreList)
                    if obstructs[1] then
                        return
                    elseif not obstructs[1] then
                        print(object.Name.." has been detected!")
                    end
                elseif visible ~= true then
                        print("You are now incognito.")
                    return
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: Any part of a player, including arms/legs/head, or just torso?

Comment: Every single part but if it's not possible then the torso or head would be just fine.